# How can make my diagram fit into A3 page

Tags: visio

I am doing a mind map drawing on visio and I have used the auto arrange feature. This has caused the drawing to go over the stipulated page size (A3) into so many other pages. How do I bring the entire drawing back to A3 size without distorting the flow of the diagram.

I have attached a picture for a better description: [screen shot of visio diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkCjG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a newer version then me, but in Visio 2007 at least, on the File menu you can go to Page Setup. In the Print zoom settings, there're options to "fit to [x] sheets across by [y] sheets down". Setting this to 1 x 1 might do what you want, but it'll just scale it all so you might end up with rather small text!